# How can I force artisan to serve with local environment?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I tried

```
php artisan serve --env=local
```

But its still serving the development site.

```
Laravel development server started on http://localhost:8000
```

I know I can edit the app config, but for the project I'm working on I need to switch between the two modes often and thats going to be a pain.

ps. I'm using 4.2

Comment: Are both your local and development sites on the same server? I guess I don't understand because depending on where you run artisan will be the env it uses.

Comment: I'm testing locally in all cases. However I occasionally expose my local site to the web and want to make sure I don't reveal my environment variables by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but I got it to work like this.

Put at the very top of `artisan`

```
if(in_array('serve', $argv))
    if(in_array('--env=local', $argv))
        file_put_contents('.isLocal','');
    else if(file_exists('.isLocal'))
        unlink('.isLocal');
```

And replace the existing environment detection logic with this

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => file_exists('.isLocal'),
));
```

Basically artisan will now create an `.isLocal` file whenever the `--env=local` option is set and delete it when its not. Make sure to add `.isLocal` to your `.gitignore`